# MySql Update Entry with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert an entry into a database unless it already exists, in which case I just want to update the entry.

I was using:

```
let data = {data1: 'test', data2: 'test2'}; //Example
connection.query('REPLACE INTO ' + table_name + ' SET ? ', data, (err) => { //do stuff }
```

Which worked until I stared using foreign keys. I tried instead to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but it seems to require me to list all the fields. I am using this for different (and complex) tables so this isn't really suitable:

```
INSERT INTO ' + table + ' SET ? ' +
        'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {requires me to list all fields. * Doesn't seem to work}', data, err
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to list all fields. You just have to list the fields you want to update.

```
INSERT INTO table
  SET 
    field1 = 4, field2 = 55
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    field1 = VALUES(field1),
    field2 = VALUES(field2);
```

There's not much difference to a plain UPDATE or REPLACE query, where you have to name the affected fields anyway. And since you can access the values used in the INSERT statement directly in the UPDATE statement, you don't have to write them twice. Just use VALUES(field) instead of inserting the actual value repeatedly.

Comment: I want to update all the fields though, and I dont know before hand what fields need updating (or what will be in the 'SET'). The query is run in a js function it doesnt contain the names of the fields. I would need to write a query per table.

Comment: So the ? in your code snippet is set by a script? Can't this script extend the produced snippet?

Comment: Sorry, its a js dict (such as {field1: 'item', field2: 'item2'}) set by data. Updated snippet.

Comment: Now I understand. Well, I don't think you will find a solution without modifying the js script which builds the query. There's no way around naming all fields in the UPDATE ON DUP statement. And REPLACE will always stay a combination of DELETE+INSERT.